# Useless assignment - Sonar warning

Tags: c#, sonarqube

I have below piece of code in which giving me the warning of useless assignment

```cs
Agent agentInfo = new Agent();
if (_userProfile.UserType == Constants.AgentUserType)
    return agentInfo = (from agents in _eAppDataAccess.Agents.FindAll()
        where agents.AgentCode == _agentNumber
        select new Agent
        {
            Address1 = agents.Address1,
            Address2 = agents.Address2,
            PhoneNumber = agents.Phone
        }).FirstOrDefault();
else
    return agentInfo;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [tour] and [ask]. Where exactly do you get this warning? Have you tried anything? Do you understand what SonarQube is reporting? Can you explain to us what this code is doing, so we know what to explain to you? Also, you return `null` when not found by `_agentNumber`, and a `new Agent()` when `_userProfile.UserType != Constants.AgentUserType`. Is that intentional?

Comment: `.FirstOrDefault()` means that you expect that there are 0, 1, 2 or more records with that _agentNumber. If you expect exactly one, use `.Single()` to make your intent clearer (and to throw an exception when your assumption was wrong). Use `SingleOrDefault()` if you expect at most one, but maybe none.

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning `Agent agentInfo = new Agent()` and the later reassigning it without doing anything to `agentInfo`. You can leave it out and return `new AgentInfo()` in your else clause directly. Like so:

```cs
if (_userProfile.UserType == Constants.AgentUserType)
    return (from agents in _eAppDataAccess.Agents.FindAll()
        where agents.AgentCode == _agentNumber
        select new Agent
        {
            Address1 = agents.Address1,
            Address2 = agents.Address2,
            PhoneNumber = agents.Phone
        }).FirstOrDefault();
else
    return new Agent();
```

**Edit:** CodeCaster pointed something out in the comments I overlooked. You are returning `null` when an Agent wasn't found by his `_agentNumber` and a `new Agent()` when the `_userProfile.UserType` isn't of type `AgentUserType`. Is this intentional?

Answer (score 1):

Just remove assigning `agentInfo` variable and return result directly.

```
return (from agents in _eAppDataAccess.Agents.FindAll()
                                where agents.AgentCode == _agentNumber
                                select new Agent
                                {
                                    Address1 = agents.Address1,
                                    Address2 = agents.Address2,
                                    PhoneNumber = agents.Phone
                                }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: What about the else clause?